# Определить нажатие комбинации клавиш

Tags: javascript

В данном вопросе есть [ответ (усложненная версия)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1264117/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5-%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BC/1267340#1267340) приложен такой код:

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", handlerKeydown);
// ...
function handlerKeydown(event)
{
    if (event.code === "KeyF" && (event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey))
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        controlInputText.focus();
    }
}
```

Так вот, я так понимаю суть была отловить нажатие Ctrl+F. Но оно не срабатывает в Spotify, то есть если я держу Ctrl и нажимаю F, событие не видит этого. Я получаю лишь такой event:

```
KeyboardEvent {isTrusted: true, key: "Control", code: "ControlLeft", location: 1, ctrlKey: true, …}
altKey: false
bubbles: true
cancelBubble: false
cancelable: true
charCode: 0
code: "ControlLeft"
composed: true
ctrlKey: true
currentTarget: null
defaultPrevented: false
detail: 0
eventPhase: 0
isComposing: false
isTrusted: true
key: "Control"
keyCode: 17
location: 1
metaKey: false
path: (4) [body, html.no-focus-outline.spotify__os--is-windows.spotify__container--is-desktop.buddyfeed-visible, document, Window]
repeat: false
returnValue: true
shiftKey: false
sourceCapabilities: InputDeviceCapabilities {firesTouchEvents: false}
srcElement: body
target: body
timeStamp: 147413.99999998976
type: "keydown"
view: Window {window: Window, self: Window, document: document, name: "", location: Location, …}
which: 17
__proto__: KeyboardEvent
```

Из чего видим, что не ловится нажатие клавиши F. Что сделано не так?

Comment: Попробуй `document.addEventListener("keydown", handlerKeydown, true);` - то есть, на этапе захвата событие обрабатывать. А то скрипты вебприложения могут останавливать всплытие (того события, которое возникает при нажатии клавиши F).

Comment: Хотя сейчас проверил - у меня в хроме (и на главной странице спотифая, и в поиске, и в плейлисте) почему-то все нормально с обработкой событий на всплытии, т.е. проблема не воспроизводится. А в десктопной приложухе Spotify, не нашел консоль... видимо, неэлектронъ :D

Comment: Там есть spicetify, это уже так сказать для разработчкив) Попробую, спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", handlerKeydown);
// ...
function handlerKeydown(event) {
  if (event.code === "KeyF" && (event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey)) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(event.code, event.ctrlKey, event.metaKey);
  }
}

document.querySelector('input').focus();
```

```html
<input />
```

Comment: Есть шанс, что приложение просто перехватывает это нажатие?

Comment: @OliverPatterson О чем идет речь? Какое приложение?

Comment: В данном случае Spotify.

Comment: @OliverPatterson Мне плохо видны мысли у Вас в голове. В вопросе не говорится ни о каком Spotify-е.

Comment: Поправил вопрос. Плюсик я вам дал, если не будет какого-то решения другого, отмечу ваш ответ правильным.